# Remove NA and colapse columns into one column, R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have the following matrix:

```
      V1  V2  V3  V4  V4
[1,] "a" "j" "d" "e"  NA           
[2,] "a" "b" "d" "e"  NA           
[3,] "a" "j" "g" "f"  NA           
[4,] "a" "g" "f"  NA  NA
```

I want to get:

```
 V1  V2  
[1,] "ajde"             
[2,] "abde"             
[3,] "ajgf"          
[4,] "agf"
```

I know how to reduce a matrix to one column by using `matrix(do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(M)))` and how to remove the NA by row using `m[!is.na(m[i,])]`. I just do not know how to but the two together as any time I try to use m[!is.na(m)] on the whole matrix, I end up with one large row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use use `gsub` to remove the NA

```
V1 <- gsub("NA+", "", do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(M)))
V1
#[1] "ajde" "abde" "ajgf" "agf" 

matrix(V1, ncol=1)
```

---

Or we can use the traditional approach with `apply`

```
apply(M, 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=""))
```